# neo4j java query stalls out

Tags: java, neo4j

I have this code sample that I am trying to run:

```
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPI;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.query.RestCypherQueryEngine;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.QueryResult;
import java.util.Map;
import static org.neo4j.helpers.collection.MapUtil.map;

public class TestRun {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("starting test");
     final RestAPI api = new RestAPIFacade("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
     System.out.println("API created");
     final RestCypherQueryEngine engine = new RestCypherQueryEngine(api);
     System.out.println("engine created");
     final QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> result = engine.query("start n=node({id}) return n, id(n) as id;", map("id", 0));
     System.out.println("query created");
     for (Map<String, Object> row : result) {
        long id=((Number)row.get("id")).longValue();
        System.out.println("id is " + id);
     }
   }
}
```

And it seems to just be stalling at the construction of the QueryResult.  Any idea why it would just get stuck there?  No error or exception.

Comment: Have you tried running this query against the database with the neo4j shell?

Comment: I have, when I replace the map with the value (i.e. id=0) it comes back with a result (i.e. Node[0] and 0).  I have no idea why it is stalling at the current stage.

Comment: Is there any query going over the wire at all? If not, this looks like a bug, could you raise an issue at https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade to the latest version of Neo4j API (1.9 at the moment)

Comment: I also had to add a proper maven pom.xml